# C++ double indirection for pointers and multidimensional arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

So I've been trying to understand pointers more and I have came across this:

`double **DPtr; // just for example`

I have read that it can be used to point to an multidimensional array but i couldn't make it work until i used single indirection sign (`*`).

So, if I can't use double indirection for multidimensional array, what is it for?

I tried to find an answer but I had no luck.

Thanks in advance for any information you'll give me! :)

Comment: You **can** use double pointers to create your own multidim arrays.

Comment: If you're only interested in arrays, use `std::vector` or `std::array`. It's much simpler than playing with pointers.

Comment: @us2012 Depends on what you mean. There's no way to turn a `double[X][Y]` into a `double**` which could be dereferenced safely.

Comment: @Angew It didn't occur to me that this was what the OP was looking for. Edited my comment to exclude that situation.

Comment: @Hiura The question explicitly says that they're trying to understand pointers, which is a good idea in general, even if there are better solutions available for many practical problems.

Comment: @us2012 That's why it's a comment and not an answer – *maybe* (s)he thought there was no other way to use arrays. ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question is not too clear. You can use a `double**` to create your own 2-D array, with a lot of manual bookkeeping:

```
const size_t dim1 = 10, dim2 = 20;

double **arr;
arr = new double*[dim1];
for (size_t idx = 0; idx < dim1; ++idx) {
  arr[idx] = new double[dim2];
}
double[4][5] = 3.14;
```

The array could even be "jaggy" in the sense that each the size of the "secondary" array can be different for each "primary" index.

However, it's actually an array of pointers to arrays, it's not a real 2-D array because it's not contiguous in memory. If you instead create a real 2-D array:

```
double arr[dim1][dim2];
```

then there's no way to safely convert this to a dereferencable `double **p`. The reason is that the memory at address `p[2]` stores a pointer to `double`, while the memory at address arr[2] stores a `double` (first one from an array of `double`s).

**EDIT**

Based on your "main question" you expressed in comments: double indirection is less useful in C++ than it is in C. C does not have references, so if you want a function to provide an output parameter of pointer type, it has to take a double pointer. Example:

```
void allocate(int style, char **arr)
{
  switch (style) {
    case 0: *arr = malloc(100); break;
    case 1: *arr = malloc(200); break;
    default: *arr = malloc(300); break;
  }
}

int main(void)
{
  char *a;
  allocate(1, &a);  //this way, allocate can modify a
}
```

In C++, you'd achieve the same by passing the pointer by reference:

```
void allocate(int style, char * &arr)
{
  switch (style) {
    case 0: arr = new char[100]; break;
    case 1: arr = new char[200]; break;
    default: arr = new char[300]; break;
  }
}

int main()
{
  char *a;
  allocate(1, a);  //a is passed by reference, allocate can modify it
}
```

In general, try to steer clear of raw pointers in C++ and use objects directly, or smart pointers if you need dynamic memory. Double-indirection pointers are even rarer.

Comment: is it more recommended to use this than the regular multidimensional array?

Comment: @NaorHadar No, quite contrary. Steer clear of dynamic allocation if you can, and steer clear of *manual* dynamic allocation unless you're forced to use it at gunpoint.

Answer (score 2):

Well

```
double **DPtr;
```

defines a pointer to a pointer to double. This can have different uses, specific to your question, it can be used for 2d arrays of double. However note, that

```
double* A = new double[10][10]
```

Does define one block of memory of length 100 doubles instead of one array of double pointers and into each a block of ten doubles. To have a "real" 2d array you can do something like this

```
double** A2d = (double*)[10];
for(int i=0; i<10;i++){
    A2d = new double[10]
}
```

this would create a array of 10 arrays each beeing of size 10.
Note that you can acces both types of 2d arrays in the same way, e.g.
    A[1][5]
would work for both. The real 2d array would be particular usefull, the second order arrays are of different size. But in general I would suggest to use the single pointer variant.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you can use it for a 2D array (dynamically allocated).

For example:

```
double** array;

array = new double*[10];

for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    array[i] = new double[20];
}
```

creates a 10x20 2D array that can be accessed as follow

```
//Classic syntax with subscript operator
double d1 = array[2][4];
//Obfuscate syntax using pointer arithmetics
double d2 = *(*(array+2)+4);
```

You're using an array of pointer (which can be used as arrays themselves). Still, that's quite not really practical, as well as being usafe (raw pointers are unsafe in many cases), and `std::array` or `std::vector` should be preferred.

But it can also simply be used as a pointer to a pointer (and it can go further than *double* pointers).

For example :

```
int var = 10;
int *var_ptr= &var;
int **var_dbl_ptr = &var_ptr;

std::cout << **var_dbl_ptr << std::endl;
//Prints 10
```

Answer (score 1):

A "pointer to an object" is itself an object, and hence can be itself "pointed" from ... a "pointer to (a pojinter to an object)".

Similarly an array of an object is itself an object that can be part of an "array of (array of an object)"

Now, being the "name of an array" also the "address of the first element", there is a substantial equivalence in expression between *a and a[0] (and hence *(a+n) and a[n]).

So, you can have a `double** pp` used in expression like `pp[3][4] = 3.14;`
but the mechanism is between array and pointers is different:

an array looks like

```
_ _ _ _ _ 
_ _ _ _ _
_ _ _ _ _
```

Wile a double indirection looks like

```
_ -->  _ --> _ _ _ _
       _ --> _ _ _ _ _ _
       _ --> _ _ _
```

In the first case there is a object repeated 5 times to produce a "wide object" repeated three times.

In the second case, there is a "pointer to pointer" pointing to a "group of three pointers", pointing each to an independent group of objects (with independent sizes).